# Am I initializing 'd3-context-menu.js' wrong?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to use the [d3-context-menu](https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu) lib but the [example file](https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu/blob/master/examples/index.htm) wasn't working for me – the *d3-context-menu* code wasn't getting initialized.

I didn't know the "right" way to do it – but in my non-es6, d3 Electron/Node project I got it working through the steps below. I am no JS hero. In my searches I saw a lot of stuff about "Node edge" and "Babel transpiling" but I try hard not to dump in code and coding approaches I don't understand

**Is there anything wrong with the way I am doing it?**

1. putting the *d3-context-menu.js* file in my js directory, along with the associated css file in my css directory and referencing it from the main index.html
2. in my main script I initialize *d3-context-menu.js* like this:

   ```
   let d3 = require('./js/d3')  
   let d3contextMenuLib = require('./js/d3-context-menu')  
   let d3ContextMenu = d3contextMenuLib(d3);
   ```
3. finally, I attach the event listeners to the objects that should get them (I don't need the "onOpen"/"onClose " functions shown in the example code).

   ```
   .on('contextmenu', d3ContextMenu(eventMenu));
   ```

Comment: You're using `let` instead of `var`, making your code ES6.

Comment: @connexo - thanks for the comment. That's part of what confused me – I tried using ES6 `import contextMenuFactory from 'd3-context-menu';` as mentioned in the comment [here](https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu/issues/27) but was getting errors – so I got confused.